# Determine the law of $F^{-1}(U)$, $U$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

i'm trying to understand the following problem

> Let $X$ be a real random variable, its distribution function is $F(t):\Bbb{P}(X\le t), \forall t\in \Bbb{R}$. Define the right-continuous inverse by 
>   \begin{equation}F^{-1}(u) := \inf\{x\in \Bbb{R}:F(x)>u\} \qquad (a)\end{equation}
>   If $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ find the law of $F^{-1}(U)$

I tried to solve the problem in the following way: what we are looking for is $F_{F^{-1}(U)}(y)$
$$F_{F^{-1}(U)}(y) = P(F^{-1}(U)\le y) =P(U\le F(y)) = \int_0^{F(y)}1\, dt = F(y)$$

However i think that i'm doing some error above, because the solution of the problem states:

*We have*

$$P(F^{-1}(U)\le a) \overset{(1)}{=} P\left( \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(U<F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}F(a+\frac{1}{n}) = F(a)$$

Is what i've done wrong the result are equal but i don't see the reasoning behind $(1)$. Can someone explain me the step $(1)$?  I think that $(1)$ comes from the definition $(a)$, but i can't prove it. Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: what you have written is not wrong. Step (1) use the fact the $F$ is right continuous.

Comment: I think, this is an exercise to show how to use the right continuity.

Comment: @Lost1 could you please tell me how to use right continuity to rewrite $F^{-1}(U)\le a$ as $\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}$? i've really tried to understand this, but i still can't get it

Comment: @OBDA You are in the same class as me :). Did you understand the solution of exercise $2, ii)$ of the exercises sheet 7?

Comment: oh which university do you attend, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @Lost1 Zürich :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

well the first thing equals to $P({U\leq F(a)})$ by monotonicity of the function $F$.

Claim:

$\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}=\{U\leq F(a)\}$

Proof: clearly $\{U\leq F(a)\}\subset\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}$, since $\{U\leq F(a)\}\subset \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}$ for every $n$

To see the reverse direction:

For some $\omega \in  \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}$, suppose that $U(\omega)>F(a)$, then there exists $n$ such that $U(\omega)>F(a+1/n)$ since $F$ is increasing and right continuous.

Comment: @Lost1 but $\bigcup_n\{U\le F(a-\frac1n)\}\neq\bigcap_n\{U<F(a+\frac1n)\}$ in this case, right ?

Comment: @OBDA not generally, because the function $F$ is only known to be right-continuous (by definition $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach worked in the case of the uniformly-distributed random variable, because $F$ is continuous and differentiable on $[0,1]$ -- so you are able to integrate the density function.

For a random variable in general the distribution function is non-decreasing and right-continuous -- but could have jump discontinuities.

The reasoning behind (1) is if $E_n$ constitute a contracting sequence of events, then

$$P(\cap_{k=1}^{n}E_k)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(E_n)$$

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help, however the reasoning i don't get behind $(1)$ was not the step
$$P\left( \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(U<F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$

but the step 

$$P(F^{-1}(U)\le a) = P\left( \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}\right)=$$

Comment: F is non-decreasing. You can show the events are the same. Try assuming there is an $\omega$ elementary outcome that is in one but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the distribution of $F^{-1}(X)$ is always $U[0,1]$, regardless of the underlying random variable. It just happens that with the simple case of when you already start with a standard uniform, you just get one back. This is just from the definition of a CDF.

Also, I don't see why you think you got a different answer: You've concluded that the probability that the inverse transform of a uniform is less than a value is equal to the CDF of the random variable. So did the "solution". The only difference I see is that they are using $a$ instead of $y$. Also, you relied on integration while the solution relied on limits, which is a more general approach. But you are not wrong in this case.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! May i ask you if you understood step $(1)$ as well? If yes, could you please give me a hint or explain it to me?

Comment: @Ale Note that for $\left( \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{U < F(a+\frac{1}{n})\}\right)$ to be true, it has to be true for every value of $n\geq1$ because you are taking intersections. Therefore, this effectively eliminates all values of $n<\infty$, thus this is just a set-theoretic way of writing the first inequality. It's needed to formulate the limiting argument in the following steps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it now! Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

To compute $\mathbf P\left(F^{-1}(U) \le a\right)$, we should understand the event $\{F^{-1}(U) \le a\}$ better. Notice that if $F^{-1}(U) \equiv \inf\{y : F(y) > U\}$, then by definition of the infimum, for every $n\ge 1$ we have
$$
F\left(F^{-1}(U)+\frac{1}{n}\right) > U.
$$
If $F^{-1}(U) \le a$, then by monotonicity, $a$ has the property that for every $n\ge 1$,
$$
F\left(a + \frac{1}{n}\right) > U.
$$
Conversely, if $F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right) > U$ for every $n$, then $a$ is **at least** as big as $\inf\{y : F(y) > U\}$, i.e. $a\ge F^{-1}(U)$. Hence we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf P\left(F^{-1}(U) \le a\right) &= \mathbf P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{U<F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}\right)
\end{align*}
because the two events inside $\mathbf P(\dots)$ are equal. Now, the events inside the second set of parentheses are nested, so
\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{U<F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf P\left(U < F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&= F(a),
\end{align*}
where the second equality uses the definition of $U$ and the last equality follows by right-continuity of the distribution function $F$.